# How to fetch data from service without refreshing the page in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

`home.ts` fetches data from a service using the below code in its `OnInit()` function:

```
 this._http.get(this._url+this.SNO+"&"+this.randomno,{headers:headers})
   .subscribe(data => {this.list=data.json();
```

Now this page has a field to add new record. Once user adds the record, I am basically reloading the page using below code:

`this.navCtrl.setRoot(CommunicationPage`

I want to refresh the data without reloading the page, how do I do this?

Comment: ionViewDidEnter(){ } method is better option rather than refreshing the page.

Comment: you mean i call method in this function ? and just call this function once record is added

Comment: no just put your calling function inside this method and then try to add data. No need To call this method it is inbuilt provided by ionic.

Comment: once i chat then how will ionic understand to reload from server  ?

Comment: i am fetching data `OnInit` , once user sends chat message i am calling `ionViewDidEnter()` and fetching my data from this function aswell with a 2 seconds delay, in console.log, my array is showing `11 items in array` when page loads and after adding chat it still shows `11 items in array` whereas it should have shown 12.. i am going to pastebin my code, please advise accordingly..

Comment: u check the working on ionViewDidEnter() and then try may be it will useful.

Comment: Welcome ,Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

In my example I keep all my params to a data variable

```
data: any = {};
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
        this.data = {...params};
        this.countriesService.getCountries(this.data).subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.countries = res.data.countries
        })
    });
}
```

and when I want to "refresh" my data list I'm doing this

```
searchCountries() {
    this.data.random = Math.random();
    this.router.navigate([], {queryParams: this.data });
}
```

Is that what you looking for?

Comment: i have a chat page, chat is being saved on server side, once you chat, you data is saved in server, now at this time i want to load data from server again without refreshing

Comment: I'm not refreshing the whole page. I'm just trigger the queryParams observable by changing the url by adding or chaning a random number

Comment: i am fetching data `OnInit` , once user sends chat message i am calling `ionViewDidEnter()` and fetching my data from this function aswell with a 2 seconds delay, in console.log, my array is showing `11 items in array` when page loads and after adding chat it still shows `11 items in array` whereas it should have shown 12.. i am going to pastebin my code, please advise accordingly..

Comment: my code `https://pastebin.com/qWDR1Jdb`  , have a look at `OnInit` and `onsubmit` which is calling `this.ionViewDidEnter();` after 2 seconds but array result of `data.json()` is still same, please advise